# Why does these two prolog codes give back different result?

Tags: prolog

```
call((append(As,Bs,[1,2,3,4]),writeq(user,append(As,Bs,[1,2,3,4])))).
```

Result:

```
append([],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])
As = [],
Bs = [1,2,3,4] ? ;
append([1],[2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])
As = [1],
Bs = [2,3,4] ? ;
append([1,2],[3,4],[1,2,3,4])
As = [1,2],
Bs = [3,4] ? ;
append([1,2,3],[4],[1,2,3,4])
As = [1,2,3],
Bs = [4] ? ;
append([1,2,3,4],[],[1,2,3,4])
As = [1,2,3,4],
Bs = [] ? ;
no
```

But if I try this:

```
 call((append(As,Bs,[1,2,3,4]) -> writeq(append(As,Bs,[1,2,3,4])) ; writeq('There are no solutions.\n'))).
```

It gives back this:

```
append([],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])
As = [],
Bs = [1,2,3,4] ? ;
no
```

What is the difference? I try to write it so that it can tell if there are 0 solutions.

Comment: `->` is an if-then-else. It commits to the first answer.

Comment: Nicer way to formulate this: `G_0 = append(As,Bs,[1,2,3,4]), call(G_0), writeq(G_0)`